# Including previous predictions as features in time series forecasting

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, random-forest, cart, data-imputation

I have a time series that I am trying to model using a Random Forest of regression trees as part of the scikit-learn ensemble library. In order to prepare the model for forecasting, I have included as features the five previous hourly target values in the training set, among other features:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------+
| n-1 | n-2 | n-3 | n-4 | n-5 |          y |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------+
| 10  | 11  | 4   | 36  |  18 |         15 |
| 15  | 10  | 11  | 4   |  36 |          4 |
|  4  | 15  | 10  | 11  |   4 |         21 |
| 21  |  4  | 15  | 10  |  11 |          9 |
|  9  | 21  |  4  | 15  |  10 |         55 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------+
```

However, when I use the model to predict future values (say, 5 hours into the future), I face a similar imputation question: how should I fill the null values?

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------+
| n-1 | n-2 | n-3 | n-4 | n-5 |       yhat |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------+
| 11  | 31  | 42  |  6  |  12 |         15 |
| NA  | 11  | 31  | 42  |   6 |          4 |
| NA  | NA  | 11  | 31  |  42 |         21 |
| NA  | NA  | NA  | 11  |  31 |          9 |
| NA  | NA  | NA  | NA  |  11 |         55 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------+
```

1. One idea is to predict one row at a time, and then use the predictions to fill the values in the subsequent row. One reason this might be bad is that the prediction values are probably off themselves, and so I am just compounding (potentially) my errors as I get further into the future (but which may be inevitable anyway).
2. The other idea is, if only "n-1" is missing, just fill it with "n-2". But there will be rows for which all "n-1" to "n-5" are missing. In that case, I suppose they could just be filled with whichever were the most recent "n-1" to "n-5" values from the recent past.

Is one (or some strategy not considered) to be preferred?

Comment: I was facing similar challenge when i tried using auto.arima in forecast package. This uses ARIMA with external regressors. I had the same idea as that of yours for first method you pointed. It worked quite well with a low Mean Absolute Percentage Error than if i did not include it. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189983/time-series-with-autoregressive-distributed-lags-forecasting-for-future

Comment: I also work on a similar problem - I also use the first method you mentioned. You are right that errors can propagate this way - you can only try to minimise this by making your model as accurate as possible. In any case, it is expected that your predictions that are further into the future will be less reliable, so it is easy to explain.

Answer (score 1):

- You will have a 'burn-in' period for the first time points before *t1*, when you generate descriptors' looking *t1* time backwards. Also if you forecast interval is *t2*, you will have a 'burn-out' period *t2* of the the last time points.
- To build a fair RF model you will probably need 150-5000 samples depending on how difficult the task is. Then burning some few time points in either end does not matter much. If your model only has ~30 time points, strongly consider other forecasting priciples: linear regression, auto-regresion, ARIMA etc.
- I don't think your future prediction performance will improve by imputing NAs.
- Bonus advice: If your time series is not stationary, consider computing the first derivative (change/time) and model this instead. Otherwise your model will end up forecasting the next value as something very close to the last value. Such predictions are trivial and often useless.

**disclaimer**: I'm only a "time series hobbyist" :)